# php % (mod function) goes to negative on large numbers. How to get rid of it?

Tags: php

How do I use % properly not to get negative result?

```
<?php 
    $x = 1103515246*12345;
    echo $x." ".decbin($x)."</BR>";
    $y = $x % (1 << 15);
    echo $y." ".decbin($y)."</BR>";
?>
```

Output:

```
13622895711870      11010011110111000001011001111110

-27010              11111111111111111001011001111110
```

RESOLVED

`$y = bcmod($x,(1 << 15));` Solves the issue. Thank you for quick help! It was my first question!

Comment: I get different results (5758 for the second echo). What version of PHP are you using?

Comment: @ChrisHanson, I suppose you have 64but system

Comment: You might want to read up on [how PHP handles integers](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.integer.php). *"If PHP encounters a number beyond the bounds of the integer type, it will be interpreted as a float instead. Also, an operation which results in a number beyond the bounds of the integer type will return a float instead."*

Comment: Probably 5.1 or 5.2. Default Eclipse PHP.

Comment: This isn't a [PHP version issue](http://3v4l.org/piDoj), it's a hardware issue. Using a 32-bit machine, you'll get [this result](http://codepad.org/UzFGbPS8). Using a 64-bit machine, you'll get [the correct result](http://viper-7.com/v8cBbV).

Comment: My machine is 64 bit and Eclipse is as well.

Comment: This is an example of Integer Overflow

Answer (score 9, accepted):

problem is that `$x` not `integer` but `float` and casted to negative `int` when you use `%`

Try use `BCMath` instead for big numbers